# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: FacesContext.getAttributes()Ljava/util/Map

Tags: java, servlets, primefaces, jsf-2.2, servlet-filters

I have this simple `SessionFilter` added into my project but whenever `chain.doFilter` is executed, it throws error -

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes()Ljava/util/Map;**

**SessionFilter.java**

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (!(req instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        HttpServletResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            @Override
            public String encodeRedirectUrl(String url) {
                return url;
            }

            @Override
            public String encodeRedirectURL(String url) {
                return url;
            }

            @Override
            public String encodeUrl(String url) {
                return url;
            }

            @Override
            public String encodeURL(String url) {
                return url;
            }
        };
        try {
            chain.doFilter(req, wrappedResponse); //Exception here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

I have below configurations in my project.

- **Dynamic Web Module - 3.0**
- **Java - 1.7**
- **JavaServer Faces - 2.2**
- **PrimeFaces - 5.0**
- **Server - JBoss - 7.0**

I tried finding any solution for this but I couldn't get any help. Since this is my first Java Faces Project, I am really not getting any ideas to solve this. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you've added jsf-api-2.2.jar in your classpath but as you're using JBoss - 7.0 as a container, it itself comes with jsf-api-1.2_13.jar. So there is a conflict and 1.2 version is getting the preferences as it is from the container and will be loaded first. As javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes()is introduced from jsf 2.0, this is why that exception is thrown. Replacing the old jar with the new one might work for you.

Comment: Worked on well Sharique.. Thanks much.. :)